# What are the complete legal entities that can be put in a namespace?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ now. What are the complete legal entities that can be put in a namespace?

Legal entities here means valid members of a namespace

Oh, this is a real question. I'm coming from .net and I have the .net mindset.

Comment: What's a "complete legal entity"?

Comment: Perhaps if you could give a couple of examples of things you think are allowed, and things you think aren't, people may be able to work out what you mean.

Comment: "I'm learning Japanese now. What are the complete legal entities that can be put before the particle 'wa'?" This is a horrible approach to learning any language - computerized or otherwise - or to learning any **thing**, really.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: After the fun, please help me now ...

Comment: I am not having fun. I am trying to help you, to not waste your time on wondering about something useless.

Comment: @Karl: I don't know any Japanese and don't understand your analogy, but to draw my own, it would be perfectly reasonable when learning a natural language to ask, "what are the legal tenses of a verb?", or when learning HTML to ask, "what elements are legal inside a p element?". In other words, "what are my options here?". That seems to me to be all that Tupa is asking -- you could look at a formal statement of the grammar to see what productions are legal, although of course in C++ there are also semantic restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Any code can be put inside namespace.

However `main()` function **must be** at global namespace. It **cannot** be put inside user-defined namespace.

```
namespace userns
{
  int main() 
  {
     return 0; 
  }
}
```

This program wouldn't <del>compile</del> link : http://www.ideone.com/k6SPc

Its because `userns::main()` will not be considered entry-point of the program; it became just like any other user function, not the standard `main()`.  To compile it successfull, you've to add `main()` at global namespace:

```
namespace userns
{
  int main() 
  {
     return 0; 
  }
}

int main() 
{
     return 0; 
}
```

This will <del>compile</del> link now : http://www.ideone.com/76Ynu

Comment: `This program wouldn't compile`. It compiles, it doesn't link. Putting `main()` inside `namespace` is legally allowed (as your 2nd example suggests). Just that the entry point should be a global `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Anything can be put in a namespace (which is legal for `C++`, of course).

Actually, everything is in some namespace - the global namespace, if not specified.

Comment: Are macros in a namespace ? I don't think they *can* be put in a namespace ... that's why you have to prefix them ...

Comment: No one can stop you putting macros in a namespace. What this does is something else.

Comment: You cannot put anything in `namespace`. There are few restrictions. I have described in my answer.

Comment: I don't agree with the restrictions in your answer. I don't say they are wrong. I'm just saying, that there are a lot of things like this, that can be written. But they are just logically wrong. It's like - "put one function in namespace A and call it from namespace B, without specifying the scope or including the whole namespace" - of course this is not allowed, but.. is it a restriction in the meaning, @Tupa asks? So many such things. So, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be put in `namespace` except few "entities", which will **not compile**.

(1) Globally overloaded `operator new` and `operator delete`

```
namespace N
{
  void* operator new (size_t size) // error
  { ... }
}
```

(2) Definition of the constructs which are declared in outer scope of the `namespace`; for example you have a `class A` declared globally then you cannot define its method inside your `namespace N`. In the same way, if you have method declared in a `namespace N` then you cannot put its definition inside `namespace N::Nested` (i.e. `Nested` is a namespace inside `N`).

```
//file
struct A {
  void foo ();
  static int i;
};

namespace N
{
  int A::i = 0; // error
  void A::foo()  // error
  {}
}
```

Demo: [this is not allowed](http://www.ideone.com/KyZ1A).

I remember at least these 2 restrictions from my experience. Don't know about specs.

Comment: More precisely: all of the definitions and declarations pertaining to a class must be in the same namespace.

Comment: @James, same thing I have covered. However, definitions can be in **outer** `namespace` also.